# MySql select digits only and order them from varchar column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column called `year varchar(100)`. This column can contain data like

```
 Year
-------
 1901
   0
 circa 12580
 125d4 great
 year 1012
 3411 standard
 12
  saf
 1234
```

Now I want to order by `Year` ascending or descending by finding the first 4 digits in the `Year` field. I want to:

1. Get only those columns those have 4 or more digits (either alone or with 
   some string)
2. Extract first 4 digits (if more than 4 or with some integer) or get 4 digits (if column has only 4 digit value)
3. Order by result set based on above two conditions

I want my result set in ascending order like:

```
Year
1012
1234
1258
1901
3411
```

And vise versa in descending order.

I have tried following:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table 
 WHERE YEAR REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND LENGTH(YEAR) = 4 
 ORDER BY CAST(YEAR AS UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

But this only returns columns having only 4 digits and orders by them, but not the result as I mentioned above.

Comment: The best practice would be to create a new column with int year, and sort by that. You may succeed on building a query to sort by an extracted regex but it will not use an index (it's important if you have many rows). If your query it's not for the production app you could create a temporary table, populate it with all the rows in the old table and normalized year value and then do a normal sort on it.

Comment: @DanIonescu I am currently on production and I cannot create column right now

Comment: ok, so the query is for the application, or it's just a one time thing for analising data once ?

Comment: it is for the application not a one time thing.

Comment: Ok how many rows has the table with the years ?

Comment: Currently 5K. But it is constantly increasing.

Comment: It's not a big deal now but it will certainly be a problem in the future if you continue adding rows, try a small refactoring: create a new column, then modify the app to use the new column, before you deploy the app change, prepare a sql script that will convert the badly formatted year in a number format, deploy the app, run the script, then you can delete the old column from the database

Comment: No. I need whole values in many other cases as well. So need to stick with this column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have solved the problem. I have created a stored function taking help from [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24855357/Get-ONLY-the-numbers-out-of-a-string-MySQL-SQL.html) (reply from Ushastry) that looks like

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_numeric`(`year` VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS INT(11)
            NO SQL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE ctrNumber VARCHAR(50);
            DECLARE finNumber VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT ' ';
            DECLARE sChar VARCHAR(2);
            DECLARE inti INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
                IF LENGTH(year) > 0 THEN
                    WHILE(inti <= LENGTH(year)) DO
                        SET sChar= SUBSTRING(year,inti,1);
                                SET ctrNumber= FIND_IN_SET(sChar,'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');

                                IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN
                            SET finNumber=CONCAT(finNumber,sChar);
                                ELSE
                            SET finNumber=CONCAT(finNumber,' ');
                                END IF;
                        SET inti=inti+1;
                    END WHILE;
                    RETURN finNumber;
                ELSE
                    RETURN 'Invalid';
                END IF;
        END
```

And then following query works as expected

```
 SELECT id, YEAR, SUBSTRING(`get_numeric`(YEAR),1,4) AS act_year FROM table HAVING LENGTH(act_year) = 4 ORDER BY act_year ASC;
```